# What's the difference between "c&&c" and "[c&&c]" in Java's regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

With this call,

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[c&&c]", "c"));
```

I got `true`. However, with this call,

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("c&&c", "c"));
```

I got `false`. The second call does not get any exceptions thrown, which means it's a valid regular expression. **However, I'm not sure that's acceptable because, in Java API, the operator `&&` seems to only occur between brackets.** Then, what's the meaning of `&&` in the second call?

Comment: Did you look at the [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the meaning of && in the second call ?

`[c&&c]` is **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** with means either of the characters in it.

> I got true.

Because `c` matches either of `c&&c`. Basically `[c&]` will be enough.

`c&&c` means literally. `c` followed by `&` followed by `&` followed by `c`. Which does not match just `c`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the first point: `[c&&c]` is a character class consisting of `c`, `&`, `&`, or `c` -- which is of course equivalent to a class consisting of `c` or `&`, which is what Rahul was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

- `[]` allow you to match any characters between them. So `[c&&c]` allows `c` or `&` to appear in the string that you are trying to match. So you get a successful match for just `c` or for just `&`
- `c&&c` is a literal which will only match with `c&&c` appearing within a text. So it doesn't match with your test string `c`.